# Obtener solo 1 Item de una coleccion en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

espero que puedan ayudarme.

Tengo este query en laravel

```
$poa = DB::table('poa_formatos')
                ->join('entities', 'poa_formatos.entity_id', '=', 'entities.id')
                ->join('acciones_especificas', 'acciones_especificas.poa_formatos_id', '=', 'poa_formatos.id')
                ->join('acciones_poa', 'acciones_poa.accion_especifica_id', '=', 'acciones_especificas.id')
                ->join('objetivos_nacionales', 'poa_formatos.obj_nacional_id', '=', 'objetivos_nacionales.id')
                ->select('entities.name as nombre_ente', 'acciones_especificas.*', 'acciones_especificas.id as id_accion', 'acciones_especificas.nombre as accion_nombre', 'objetivos_nacionales.item', 'objetivos_nacionales.redaccion as obj_nacional', 'poa_formatos.*')
                ->where('poa_formatos.entity_id', '=', $entity->id)
                ->get();

    dd($poa);
```

Con el dd me devuelve la siguiente coleccion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para obtener solo el id_accion? quiero hacer un dd que me traiga solo este Item porque lo necesito para otro query. Osea algo como $poa->id_accion!

No sé si me explico, espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si necesitas filtrar tu consulta por el `id_seccion`, porque no lo colocas en tu condicion del where?. O existen mas registros con ese `id_seccion`?

Comment: Necesito hacer otra consulta y la condicion seria el id_accion! osea quiero sacar el id_accion de la variable $poa para ponerlo como condicion en otra consulta.

Comment: Usando `fisrt()` en vez de `get()` te trae la unica consulta que necesitas para hacer el `$poa->id_accion`, el problema es que tu tienes varios con el mismo `id` y el `first()` te traera solo el primer registro que encuentre con ese `id`

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda amigo! hice el where en la vista, osea en el blade.

Comment: ¿ya fue resuelto? No se entiende mucho realmente

Answer (score 0):

En tu select puedes hacer algo asi:

```
->select('acciones_especificas.id as id_accion')
```

Answer (score 0):

agrega el siguiente codigo al final de tu consulta, intenta reemplazarlo por el ->get()

```
->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no te he entendido mal, quieres todos los id_accion que saca esa consulta pero solo esos campos, no?
En ese caso sería asi:

```
$poa = DB::table('poa_formatos')
                ->join('entities', 'poa_formatos.entity_id', '=', 'entities.id')
                ->join('acciones_especificas', 'acciones_especificas.poa_formatos_id', '=', 'poa_formatos.id')
                ->join('acciones_poa', 'acciones_poa.accion_especifica_id', '=', 'acciones_especificas.id')
                ->join('objetivos_nacionales', 'poa_formatos.obj_nacional_id', '=', 'objetivos_nacionales.id')
                ->where('poa_formatos.entity_id', '=', $entity->id)
                ->get()->pluck('acciones_especificas.id');
```

En caso de ser eso lo que buscas, no necesitas llamar al metodo select, ya que solo quieres obtener ese campo.